# Extended WPF toolkit turn off grid localization

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

When I am using Extended WPF toolkit datagrid in my bin folder as a result I got bunch of localize folders, like:

[image]

I don't need grid localization. Is there a way to turn-off localization for DataGrid?

Comment: These are resources files associated to the library. Do you really care about that ?

Comment: `Bin` folder is a *trash* folder (similar to `obj`, it contain useful stuff, which is useless to distribute). It's often filled with not used by your application files: dll and resources (localization, xml, pdb, etc.) from libraries, vshost, manifests. Simply don't think about it and don't include what you don't need into installation packages.